# Why doesn't this simple code work without " android:textIsSelectable="true" "?

Tags: android, textview, clipboard, selectable

I have this code for copying from `TextView` to clipboard but if you don't add `android:textIsSelectable="true"` this code doesn't work. Why? 
I mean if you don't use this code and just add `android:textIsSelectable="true"` you can copy `TextView` to clipboard but in API >=11 so when I use this code for API <11 , I expect it to work without adding `android:textIsSelectable="true"` but it doesn't. Why ???

```
txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

final int startIndex = txt.getSelectionStart();
final int endIndex = txt.getSelectionEnd();
final String stringYouExtracted = txt.getText().toString().substring(startIndex, endIndex);
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
```

Comment: You should accept my answer to avoid to keep this question w/o an answer. I write this because from your last answer you understand what i wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
android:textIsSelectable
```

Has been added in API > 11, so you cannot use it in API < 11. You cannot select text in a TextView before API 11!

[Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextIsSelectable%28boolean%29).

Comment: Are you sure ? we cannot select text in a textView befor API 11 ??

Comment: so this code is unusefull ????? because if you add just "android:textIsSelectable"  you can copy to clipboard .....

Comment: You can use it for recent android versions if you want